# Implementing iAds Correctly in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, iad

I have implemented iAds into my app, but I'm getting very odd errors when I run the app on the simulator. They tend to vary, but the most common error is `Error in Loading Banner!  Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=4 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Application has iAd Network configuration error" UserInfo=0xa368250 {ADInternalErrorCode=4, ADInternalErrorDomain=ADErrorDomain, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Application has iAd Network configuration error}`

And lately:
`Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Banner view is visible but does not have content" UserInfo=0xa3a0c40 {ADInternalErrorCode=5, ADInternalErrorDomain=ADErrorDomain, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Banner view is visible but does not have content}`

I can't figure out why this is happening. I double checked to make sure that the simulator is connected to wifi, and the clock is correctly set as well. This is how I implemented iAds:

Relevant code in the .h:

```
    #import "iAd/ADBannerView.h"
    @interface myViewController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate> {
    ADBannerView *adView;
}
    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet ADBannerView *adView;
```

And all the relevant code in my .m:

```
@synthesize adView;
...
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    adView.delegate = self;
    adView.hidden = YES;

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
...
-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner
didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"Error in Loading Banner!  %@", error);
}

-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner{
    NSLog(@"iAd banner Loaded Successfully!");
}
-(void)bannerViewWillLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner{
    NSLog(@"iAd Banner will load!");
}
-(void)bannerViewActionDidFinish:(ADBannerView *)banner{
    NSLog(@"iAd Banner did finish");

}
```

Then I dragged an AdBannerView onto the view and connected the outlets in the view controllers. **Is this the correct way to do this?** If so, what could be causing this error? The app doesn't crash... the ads simply don't appear. Supposedly this is a common issue but I could never track down a fix.

I have enabled push notifications for my provisioning profile, and tried to find a section for iAds but could not. Could this be the issue?

I've also ensured that the AdBannerView that I'm using is exactly 320x50. I tried again this morning with the same code and it's the same issue. Should I just go ahead and assume it's an Apple / iAd issue and submit my app assuming the above is implemented correctly?

Comment: Have you seen this: http://chrisrisner.com/31-Days-of-iOS--Day-29–Advertising-with-iAd

Comment: @logixologist Yes that was actually what I went off of

Comment: then dont they address that exact error specifically?

Comment: @logixologist They do, but I've implemented the exact same thing as they did into my code and it didn't work. Also, their sample app throws the same errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must have been an issue with the iAd network. Tested exact same code a day later and it magically work now on the device.

Comment: For the rest of people coming here, I think it's good to point out that you can force 100% success rate in receiving iAds from "Settings -> Developer -> IAD DEVELOPER APP TESTING -> FillRate". Just to rule out other types of errors.

Answer (score 2):

.h file

```
#import <iAd/iAd.h>

@interface MainViewController : CDVViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate>

@end
```

.m

```
#pragma mark iAd Delegate Methods 
- (void) bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[banner setAlpha:1];
[UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void) bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[banner setAlpha:0];
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

make sure that is before your @end in your mainviewcontroller

last just drag and drop the adbanner on your storyboard and ctrl+click and drag from the banner up to file's owner under placeholders, it's the gold box icon and then hit delegate.

Comment: the animations make it so it fades in and out based on whether there's a connection. i'm aware that this is a method that can be done with less code, but this is what i use and it works perfectly

Comment: Thank you, I just implemented that and unfortunately I'm getting the same errors. Do you think it could be an issue with my provisioning profile?

Comment: it could be but most likely it isn't. have you tested it on an actual physical device? sometimes mine is a bit spotty on xcode as well. however if you already submitted your app then it does take a couple days for it to show the actual iads

Comment: wait this may seem elementary but did you remember to ad the iad framework

Comment: I've also tried a bunch of different aid sample tutorials and get the exact same error on both the simulator and device with multiple examples. Think it's an issue with iAd?

Comment: @siegs : I am doing the same as you did. Ad did show up, while I was testing on device and sim too. But now my app is on Appstore and I appstore copy ad does not show up. Can you please shed some light on that.

Comment: it's ok, now that your app is live, it will no longer show up on your sim. i talked to developer support.

Comment: FYI - You can use the following shorthand animation code now:  [UIView animateWithDuration: 1.0f animations: ^{banner.alpha = 1.0f;}];